# Running SELECT + UPDATE in a transaction has different results than UPDATE alone?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, concurrency, transactions

I'm trying to implement some business logic with JDBC but I don't understand the result I'm getting.

I have *n* threads each one executing the following pseudocode:

```
//before threads execution
m <- exec("select x from t where id = 1")

// inside thread
conn.setAutocommit(false);
//do some stuff on the db
v <- exec("select x from t where id = 1")
exec("update t set x = {v}+1 where id=1")
conn.commit();

// after threads execution
exec("select x from t where id = 1") //result should be m+n, but it isn't
```

When I run this code the *x* column of the *t* table is not increased by *n* as I expect. There is of course a problem of concurrency among all the threads.

If I substitute that code with the following code, then it works properly:

```
//before threads execution
m <- exec("select x from t where id = 1")

// inside thread
conn.setAutocommit(false);
//do some stuff on the db
exec("update t set x = x+1 where id=1")
conn.commit();

// after thread execution
exec("select x from t where id = 1") //result is be m+n
```

But since the first code is inside a transaction, shouldn't be equivalent to the second version?

I also tried to restrict the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE but I observe always the same behavior.

EDIT: I rewrote my code with a different connection per Thread and the result is the same.

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: @BilboBaggins: updated, thanks.

Comment: 'I have n threads (that share a single connection)' and in some random order are firing `connection.commit()`?! This cannot work. Get a connection pool, use proper transaction demarcation and use some form of - maybe opimistic - locking.

Comment: @blafasel: I have a connection pool for the n threads (Executors.newFixedThreadPool) and AFAIK _setAutocommit(false)_ begins a transaction so transaction demarcation should be handled properly. Am I wrong?

Comment: What means _'that share the same connection'_ then?

Comment: connection is a parameter that I pass to the threads' constructors. Is this i bad idea?

Comment: Yes this _was_ a bad idea. If you now have seperate connections there is a chance that the setting of the isolation level may work. Is it still `SERIALIZABLE`?

Comment: yep, but I still get the same result.

Comment: What does your `exec()` do? How does it replace the `{v}+1` part? But other transactions can easily update the table between the `select` and the `update` statement of your transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: why do you think that other transactions should be able to update my table between the select and the update? Isn't it prevented by the transaction? `exec` was pseudocode. The real code are just the more verbose of a queries executed as prepared statements of JDBC.

Comment: Exact behavior depends on the transaction isolation level and the database. And even then, you still can have interleaving updates between one connection updating and committing, and  then querying the data in a new transaction. And if you are sharing a single connection with multiple threads concurrently, then all bets are off.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I removed the shared connection so it should not be an issue anymore. I don't understand your point about the interleaving updates. I read and write the data inside the same transaction. This should be enough to prevent weird behavior, shouldn't it?

Comment: No you don't: you first read in an auto commit transaction, then you update in a new transaction, then you commit and then you read. Calling `con.setAutoCommit(false)` ends current auto commit transactions and starts non-auto commit transaction mode (the transaction itself will only be started at the point you need it!). Calling `conn.commit()` commits the transaction, and a new transaction will automatically be started when needed to execute the subsequent select. In other words, you have two points where an interleaving transaction can change values.

Comment: But the logic the does the update (select+update) is inside a transaction. I can remove the reads before and after this transaction and the result would not change,because what I read inside those 2 transactions is not used in the "central" transaction. Indeed I just added those 2 queries just for clarity.

Comment: A transaction won't "prevent" concurrent updates. As long as the row has not been locked other transactions can easily update the row. And the row is only locked _after_ your `update` statement, not by your `select` statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I thought that row locking and transaction demarcation were 2 different things, related to each others. But if I put my sql statements inside a transaction, even without some explicit lock, shouldn't it be enough to guarantee no race conditions on update?

Comment: Yes they are two different things. And no, a transaction - at least with the default [isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) - is not a guaranteed against race conditions. And the read-modify-write approach is a bad idea to start with. Incrementing directly in the database like in your second example is a much better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But since the first code is inside a transaction

No. Transactions are not magic that lets you ignore concurrency. They make specific, well defined promises about when data is visible, about locking, etc, but they don't make concurrency go away. See [PostgreSQL's documentation on concurrency and isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html).

There can even be concurrency effects in single-statement operations, so reducing things to a single (complex) statement won't make concurrency go away.

In this case `SERIALIZABLE` isolation will help you:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sdemo
(
    id integer primary key,
    counter integer
);

INSERT INTO sdemo VALUES (1, 1);
```

then

```sql
SESSION1                      SESSION2
BEGIN TRANSACTION
ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
                              BEGIN TRANSACTION 
                              ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SELECT counter FROM sdemo
WHERE id = 1;
-- result is '1'
                              SELECT counter FROM sdemo
                              WHERE id = 1;
                              -- result is '1'                        

UPDATE sdemo
SET counter = 2
WHERE id = 1;
-- Succeeds

                              UPDATE sdemo
                              SET counter = 2
                              WHERE id = 1;
                              -- hangs waiting on row lock
                              -- held by session 1


COMMIT;
-- Succeeds
                              -- UPDATE finishes (succeeds)

                              COMMIT;
                              -- Aborts with
                              ERROR: could not serialize access due 
                                     to concurrent update
```

because PostgreSQL detects that one xact changed the row while another read it, then the other xact tried to change it.

However, it'd be *much simpler* to `select x from t where id = 1 FOR UPDATE` in your first example. This takes a row lock that means no other transaction can modify the row before yours commits or rolls back.

Comment: I tried also the SERIALIZABLE isolation level but it doesn't appear to work. I still have the same results. The only real difference is that now two errors occasionally appear *could not serialize access due to concurrent update* and some deadlock. Of course these errors were expected.

Comment: @heapOverflow That's ... surprising. Maybe you should post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) since it's hard to see exactly what you're doing.